# Uploading images to my directory

Tags: php, mysql, directory

When uploading images into my user directory, they are going into my database fine but they are not transferring over to my server so they can show on the get request.

I have looked at all of the posts and actually copied one, but it still isn't working.

Here's my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['sub'])) {

    $target_path = "user_uploads/"; 
    $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['img_upload']['name']);


    $post = nl2br(addslashes($_POST['content']));
    if (($_FILES["img_upload"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["img_upload"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["img_upload"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
    || ($_FILES["img_upload"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
    || ($_FILES["img_upload"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
    || ($_FILES["img_upload"]["type"] == "image/png")
    && ($_FILES["img_upload"]["size"] < 2000000))
      {
      if ($_FILES["img_upload"]["error"] > 0)
        {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["img_upload"]["error"] . "<br>";
        }
      else
        {
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["img_upload"]["name"] . "<br>";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["img_upload"]["type"] . "<br>";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["img_upload"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
        echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["img_upload"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

        if (file_exists("user_uploads/" . $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["tmp_name"]))
          {
          echo $_FILES["img_upload"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
          }
        else
          {
          move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img_upload']['tmp_name'], $target_path);
            echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['img_upload']['name']).  
            " has been uploaded"; 
        }
        }
      }
    else
      {
      echo "Invalid file";
      }

    $insert = "INSERT INTO posts (user_id, post_content, post_image, img_type, img_size, post_date) VALUES ('$user_id', '$post','$target_path', '$img_type', '$img_size', NOW())";

    if ($con->query($insert) === TRUE) {
        echo "<script>window.open('home.php?=$user_name','_self')</script>";
    }
```

Comment: Please check the directory permission.

Comment: thanks for the reply raveenanigam ... but i don't know what that means ... i'm rather new to all of this

Comment: Have you tried debugging to identify where it fails?

Comment: again, i don't know how to do that ... it's not giving me any errors, and i don't know how to debug ... it's calling it correctly from the get side, it just isn't going from the site to my directory ... is there something that i am missing from my code?